# Template method enable_if specialization

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, enable-if

i have following code that does not compile.
This are two functions in a template class that takes the arguments

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<Ret>::value, Ret>::type _on_dispatched() {
    // ...
}

typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<Ret>::value, Ret>::type _on_dispatched() {
    // ....
}
```

I want to have a specialization in a member method depending on what type Ret is.

Has anybody some idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SFINAE does not work on non-template functions (member or non-member).

As Kerrek SB points out, making them non-member function templates will work. Or as Xeo points out, making them member function templates with a defaulted template argument will also work.

However, this is only working because the two `std::enable_if` conditions are **non-overlapping**. If you want to add a different overload for `int` (say), then you'll find that it doesn't scale as nicely. Depending on what you want to do, tag dispatching generally scales better than SFINAE with multiple alternatives that you want to dispatch on:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename Ret>
class Foo
{
public:
    void _on_dispatched()
    {
        // tag dispachting: create dummy of either std::false_type or std::true_type
        // almost guaranteed to be optimized away by a decent compiler
        helper_on_dispatched(std::is_void<Ret>()); 
    } 

private:
    void helper_on_dispatched(std::false_type)
    {
        // do stuff for non-void
    }

    void helper_on_dispatched(std::true_type)
    {
        // do stuff for void
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<void>()._on_dispatched();
    Foo<int>()._on_dispatched();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can, if one of the overloads is the only viable one at call time. :) http://liveworkspace.org/code/fd6e5383610d4e0d8fb17c5497991355

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Actually, no, it was not a joke. See the link, you can perfectly fine have a function with exactly the same signature where only the return type decides if it's viable. :P Also, just use `std::is_void<Ret>()`, type traits are required to derive from either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`.

Comment: Btw, [you can just make the member function a template with a defaulted parameter in C++11](http://liveworkspace.org/code/781d94df5499998947217970c1aebf2a).

Comment: @Xeo you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Nah, I like tag dispatching better.

Comment: @Xeo Oh, I thought you meant SFINAE works for non-template functions if only one is viable, the joke being that it's no longer SFINAE but just looks like it.

Answer (score 3):

SFINAE only works on templates. Your code can be made to compile with a small modification:

```
template <typename Ret>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<Ret>::value, Ret>::type _on_dispatched() { /*...*/ }

template <typename Ret>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<Ret>::value, Ret>::type _on_dispatched() { /*...*/ }
```

Usage:

```
auto q = _on_dispatched<int>();
```

You can of course not deduce the return type of a function, since it is not deducible. However, you can pack this template *inside* another template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    // insert templates here, maybe privately so

    T bar() { return _on_dispatched<T>(); }
};
```

Comment: `template<class Rx = Ret>` for the member functions, see my comment on rhalbersma's answer.

Comment: @Xeo: You mean that would save us from having to write `<T>`? Sure, why not :-)